# How to open and run the automatic notebook file when the pc is booting?

Tags: autoload, evaluation

How to open and run the automatic notebook file when the pc is booting?

I wrote a program in Mathematica and saved it as a file.
If I turn on my computer, can I make this file open and run automatically?

Comment: This is an OS-level question and not one we can answer in general here.

Comment: In Windows there is an autostart folder. Programs (or links) are executed at startup.

Comment: We need to know which Mathematica version and which operating system you are using.
On Windows 10 with Mathematica 12.2 what you want is possible, at least if you don't mind running the notebook automatically, in batch mode, neglecting StandardForm output...